# Custom Email Validation on ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I'm doing a registration form where people can register, in that I will be asking for thier email address's If i could put a `regex` validation that captures any other emails

example:

***xxx@gmail.com***, or ***xxx@ yahoo.com***, and only allow ***xxx@bat.ac.uk*** i could implement a system that sends an email to the registering person asking them to validate it. I know how to implement the email bit I'm just stuck at this validation part. hope this makes sense

Is there a way to modify the default email validation expression

> \w+([-+.']\w+)@\w+([-.]\w+).\w+([-.]\w+)*

Comment: Is this ASP.NET MVC or Web Forms?

Comment: There are heaps of email validation regex-es on the Internet. Just Google for them.

Comment: you can't validate emails using regex.there are too many corner cases where it may fail..use `.*@.*`..

Comment: its for a web form, and i tried google many times but couldn't come up with helpful answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the built in attribute for validating email address and then in addition to that, check with this regex:

```
@bat.ac.uk$
```

Then you know it's a valid email and contains what you're looking for. The validation for email is very complicated and I wouldn't advise rewriting it, so just validate with two different things.

Email address attribute: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute.aspx

Comment: how would u go on to implement this? i tried putting a normal validation to check if the email address is valid and on another custom validation i pasted what u said on the regular expression, but it didn't seem to work, if u can please help me out as I'm stuck on this without being able to progress to the next stage of my development of this webform

Answer (score 1):

If this is ASP.NET Web Forms then you can use a [`RegularExpressionValidator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) to do the job.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="SomeID"
    runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="TheControlIDToValidate"
    ErrorMessage="An error message you want to display."
    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)@\w+([-.]\w+).\w+([-.]\w+)*"
    EnableClientScript="true" />
```

This will validate the value client-side using JavaScript. However, it can be circumvented if JavaScript isn't enabled so server-side you need to do use the [`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)@\w+([-.]\w+).\w+([-.]\w+)*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(input);
```

then if the `matches.Count > 0` you're good.

---

However, if it's ASP.NET MVC you can use the [`RegularExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute.aspx) data annotation. You just add an attribute to the property on your model:

```
[RegularExpression(@"\w+([-+.']\w+)@\w+([-.]\w+).\w+([-.]\w+)*", "Some error message.")]
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise to use the default validator for checking mail is valid and add a CustomValidator implementing both CLIENT side and Server side validation.

here you can check extensions and perform the custom logic you need.

Comment: Finally found the answer to this, Thanks for the help anyway everyone]

\w+([-+.]\w+)*@bat.ac.uk

That did the job for me